# Push and append an item into a linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have a weird problem. I have this piece of code, but it doesn't work. The weird part is that inside the function, the list is changed (printf commands indicate this), but when  call this function, nothing will be added to the list (my list is not empty).

```
void pushToList(node* list, int val) {
    node* newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->value=val;

    newNode->next = list;
    list = newNode;

    printf("here, list->value = %d \n", list->value);
    printf("here, list->next->value = %d \n", list->next->value);
}

// ----------------------------------    
//    if (list==NULL) {
//        newNode->next = NULL;
//        list = newNode;
//    } else {
//        newNode->next = list;
//        list = newNode;        
//    }
```

I call this function for example in my main function like this:

```
node* node1;
pushToList(node1, 1111);
```

And here is my struct and typedef in a separate header file (that I have included in my function file):

```
#ifndef STACKELEMENT_H
#define STACKELEMENT_H

struct stackElement {
    int value;
    struct stackElement* next;
};

typedef struct stackElement node;
#endif  /* STACKELEMENT_H */
```

Another weird behavior is that I have the following function for appending an item, and this function only works if my list is not empty:

```
int appendtoList(node* head, int val) {

    node* current = head;
    node* newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof (node));

         if(newNode == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for the new node\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

    newNode->value = val;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    while (current->next) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;

    //    if (head->next == NULL) {                
    //        head->next = newNode;
    //    } else {                
    //        while (current->next != NULL) {
    //            current = current->next;
    //        }
    //        current->next = newNode;
    //    }
    //
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're passing pointer by value

Comment: Also, in `pushToList`, what happens if `list` has the value `NULL`, and in appendtoList`, what happens if `head` has the value `NULL`?

Comment: @UchiaItachi Do you mean I'm passing a value to the function when I'm calling it? "node1" is not a value, it's a pointer, so if I call the function like this: pushToList(&node1, 111); the funtion receives the first argument like this: &&node1 . That was the warning that I got from the gcc.

Comment: @H2CO3 Why did you rate me negative? I read 58 pages of lecture notes and I already did manipulate pointers in some other exercies correctly. Plus that I read 3 posts that suggested exactly the same code that I'm using here. I don't think I made a mistake asking a question after reading bunch of stuff, I did it for better understanding, and I'm sure there are many people like me who don't bother themselve to even ask.

Comment: @mbratch 1. Nothing special happens, newNode->next will be set to NULL, that should be NULL indeed. 2. I'm not sure, but I tried the other way around too, like this: if (head==NULL) {head=newNode;} else { blah blah blah} But that doesn't work too.

Comment: `appendtoList` looks like you could reference `current->` and `current` could have the value `NULL`. This doesn't address your primary question, but just an observation. To address the problem, notice in `pushToList` you assign `list =...` near the end of the function, but since `list` is call by value, the result is lost on the function return. You need a parameter `Node **plist` and assign `*plist =...`. That's what everyone's been commenting on. It's basic C protocol for returning a value in a parameter. Or, the new pointer could be the return value of the function.

Comment: Trace your program by putting it down on a paper. Modify your code according to the above suggestions. Read about passing pointers as arguments to function and repost your modified code so that we can help you further :)

Comment: @mbratch Thank you for your patience and for explaining, unlike some other impatient PRO guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use node**list as argument type in your function.

when u pass a pointer to a function like struct node *x to
 void max (struct node*p);
 the pointer is passed by value AND 
if u want to really manipulate the contents to which x points to use struct node** as the argument type and pass &x to the function.

Same logic should apply to your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the return type, i.e. the scope of a variable which in this case is a pointer variable. mbratch also pointed out this, thank you very much, but actually before reading mbratch's comment, I suddenly remembered a point from a lecture note about "accessing an object outside of its lifetime" which I think is different from "**call** by value/call by reference" problem. 
Just some clarifications for people who may run into this problem and may get confused:
since we are allocating memory for the struct *newNode* **INSIDE** the function *pushToList* (even though using dynamic memory allocation command), **the memory assigned to this variable would be free/destroyed when the function ends** and the control returns back to the callee function (in this case, main()). So you should set the return type of your function to node* (a pointer to a node struct) and in your function return the *head*. Like this:

```
node* pushToList(node* head, int val) {
    node* newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->value=val;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;     
    return head;
}
```

In *appendToList* function, in addition to this mistake, as mbracth pointed out, I was doing another mistake by checking *head->next* (although implicitly) rather than *head* itself (to see if it's NULL): if head is NULL, you can not access head->next. Indeed two answers marked as the correct answers in some other posts here on stackoverflow misleaded me to this mistake. Anyway, here is the correct way:

```
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {                
            while (current->next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = newNode;
        }
```

Comment: But why `appendToList` works in case of non-null list although we are passing pointer to list by value?

Comment: Also, if you try to create function to delete item from list with same concept (single pointer as function argument not double pointer or reference to pointer), it'll delete it properly unless it's in the head of the list?